# Why is this price for Pokémon Diamond so high?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum, physical-media

I understand that recently retro video game collecting has surged to the point where high demand is creating high prices, but does this price seem right for a NDS Pokémon game?

I walked into a GameStop the other day and spotted a genuine copy of Pokémon Diamond (no box) in the old-gen corner of the store. It was priced at $76.95. I didn't ask the clerk questions about it, so I just kinda hand-waved the price and moved on. I have been on a hunt for older Pokémon games I haven't played before and noticed that Amazon, ebay, etc... are selling these games at a much lower price. e.g. All 5 gen-3 games around $35 US. I'm assuming these cheaper versions are bootlegged, so that said... why $76.95? I've seen other NDS Pokémon games on Amazon for a much more significant markup. Are these that desirable for collectors?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can't be answered with a specific reason, and it's not about gaming itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a combination of factors, but much of it is due to the game being very popular.

Diamond sold almost 3.2 million copies between 2006 and 2013.
https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Diamond_and_Pearl_Versions

Very desirable games are rarely sold to stores. Since it is desirable, stores like GameStop tend to pay more for the game to make sure they have it in stock.

This makes the game a higher priced one for the store.